# Fixed positioned footer but also part of element flow with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am playing around with Flexbox, but have run into trouble with the following document structure

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child A">
    <div class="top-section"></div>
    <ul class="main-section">
      <li></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="child B">

  </div>
</div>
```

I want `child B` to always be fixed at the bottom of the screen, and have `child A` fill up the remaining space above `child B`.

Inside `child A`, `top-section` should always be on top with some fixed height, to which `main-section` should fill the remaining space in `child A`, and be scrollable on the y-axis.

I have tried something along the lines of

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.childA {
  flex: 4;
  width: 100%;
}

.childB {
  position   : absolute;
  bottom     : 0;
  min-height : 250px;
  max-height : 20%;
  width      : 100%;
}

.main-section {
  overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

While it correctly fixes `child B` to the bottom, it is no longer part of the element flow, and as a result, `main-section` extends beneath it and is unable to be overflown.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: conflict of interests: `and have child A fill up the remaining space above child B` (suggests flexible height) but `Inside child A, top-section should always be on top with some fixed height` (suggests fixed height) -- additionally, you are correct that `position:absolute` takes it out of the flow. how do you visualize this working? what container will scroll to show content when it does not fit the container? is it `main-section`?

Comment: nevermind re: conflict -- i see now where you refer to the top section having fixed height. and your CSS shows where `main-section` will be scrollable

Comment: is this what you're looking for in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aequalsb/mL5gtsep/ ? if so, it was done with a slight reworking of the DOM and without flexbox. let me know and i will officially post it as an answer.

Comment: It's close, the problem however is that I want to be able to resize the height of 'footer/child b' with a mouse dragging event in JS, and it would be better if the main section automatically sized itself to fit the remaining space

Comment: the javascript controlling the mouse-drag would simply need to capture 'childB.top' and 'parent.height' on mouse release, then set 'childA.bottom' = ('parent.height' - childB.top). even though the CSS initially sets these attributes with %, the actual value is automatically resolved by the browser in the DOM and available to javascript.

Comment: Alright I got it working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made this fiddle to demonstrate a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/aequalsb/mL5gtsep/

it takes advantage of absolute positioning to set `top` and `bottom` attributes appropriately so that containers will stretch to their limits without relying on specific widths and heights.

even though the CSS initially sets the attributes with %, in the DOM the lengths are calculated by the browser, and available to javascript/jQuery as specific px lengths -- which the OP could then use to perform a mouse-drag action to resize the containers.